# 'Help' Bug found in Nest home hub and phone based Google Assistant logic

Tags: actions-on-google

I have found what I think is a Google Assistant bug. If the intent of any action you are connecting to uses the word 'Help' to initiate a help conversation. Nest Hub's own help screen kicks in immediately shutting down your conversation.

This seems to affect all display devices including google assistant running on phones. Only resolution is to get users to say 'Assist' rather than 'Help'.

This is replicated as follows:

You connect to your invocation as normal saying 'Talk to (invoked action name)' or connect to any Google action that allows you to ask for 'Help'. 
You could also create a dialogflow action that has an intent that listens for the word 'Help' and responds with some dialog.

If you say 'Help' whilst in the action. The google hub's help routine showing what you can do with Google Assistant kicks in immediately disconnecting your conversation displaying the screen telling you about things you can ask it (What you get when you say 'Hey google Help') .

This feature seems to only recently have been introduced.

I'd like to confirm others are getting this unwanted feature too.

Comment: I just tried with Number Genie and wasn't able to get the same behavior you did.

Comment: Had a look at Number Genie. This sample does note fit the criteria used to replicate the issue. there is no intent which is listening to the training phrase 'Help'. Hope this helps. have also visited a number of sites I do not own. (talk to AGL is one here in Australia) and they show the same symptoms so its not only me. I dont think the site owners are aware of the issue.

Comment: Is there an example of one I can try in the US?

Comment: you can build your own. Create a dialogflow agent, set it to have the training phrase of 'help' and return a text response of  whatever you want. This will behave in the same way.